# Removing unwanted text outside <>

Tags: c#, .net, string, textbox

I want to remove all text except the text within `<>`'s from a textbox.

Comment: Please clarify what it is you want to do - remove all text except for that characters < and > or remove all text except for any text contained between a < and >.

Comment: therir is emails like this www.abc.com <abc@gmail.com>
and i want to remove extra text this "www.abc.com"

Answer (score 1):

This is off the top of my head, but hopefully will steer you in the right direction :)

```
String email = "www.abc.com <abc@gmail.com>";
String result = "";

int firstIndex = email.IndexOf('<'); 
int lastIndex = email.IndexOf('>');
if(lastIndex > firstIndex)
    result = email.Substring(firstIndex + 1, lastIndex-firstIndex-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var strText = "asdasd<data1>sdsdf <data2>sdfsfsdf";
var pattern = new Regex(@"\<(?<data>(.+?))\>");
var matches = pattern.Matches(strText);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Data: " + match.Groups["data"]);
} 
//Output:
//Data: data1
//Data: data2
```