# removing unwanted text

Tags: c#, regex, textbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [removing unwanted text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154587/removing-unwanted-text)

I want to remove extra text:

```
test is like that www.abc.com dsfkf ldsf <info@abc.com>
```

I want to get only the email text in C#

Comment: It might be a little easier if there were actually an e-mail address in your sample.

Comment: @Joel - You edited out the email address, I'm not sure why, that was a perfectly valid address, you don't know the reason it was in brackets or what the source was.  Reverting your change, since the question makes no sense after that.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154587/removing-unwanted-text.  Please ask once

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
string textInBrackets = Regex.Match(yourText, "(?<=<)[^>]*(?=>)").ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all emails from text, you can try this:

```
List<string> foundMails = new List<string>();
string regex = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";
string text = "some text mail@something.com some other mail test.simple@something.net text.";
Match m =  Regex.Match(text, regex);
while (m.Success)
{
     foundMails.Add(m.ToString());
     m = m.NextMatch();

}
```

foundMails collection contains found emails